# Safari Browser Bar - no longer functioning as expected

Tags: safari, search

Please help! 
The search / address bar in Safari normally autocompletes my typing. So for example, I can type em and it will autocomplete for me. It has randomly stopped functioning and is now forcing me to type a complete web address before it will take me to a site. 
Secondly, I can normally type a word and press return and it will fire up google (my preferred search engine) with a list of suggestions but it has just stopped. 
I don't remember changing anything - any suggestions its incredibly frustrating! 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in safari.

Currently the workaround is to open Safari > Preferences > Search and disable "Include Safari Suggestions".

http://www.engadget.com/2016/01/27/apple-safari-suggestions-bug/